# TF record shows different tensor shape than the tensor which was serialized and stored in it

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a processed image tensor (say 25x25x1 tensor) which i am storing in a TFRecord file. I am using the tf.Example approach for serialization and preparing the TFRecord file.

When I am reading it back, the tensor is showing a shape of (644,?) and i am unable to reshape it back into 25x25x1. I am wondering how those extra values came into the tensor.

How can I fix this problem? Please help.

I am following the code sample provided by Chip Huyen here - https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials/blob/master/2017/examples/09_tfrecord_example.py

This is the code I am using for writing the file.

```
channels = 1
resize_height = 25
resize_width = 25

target_file = ./some_JPEG_file.jpeg
shape = np.array([resize_height, resize_width,channels],np.int32).tobytes()

def return_image_resized(filename,channels):
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [resize_height, resize_width],method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
  if channels ==1:
    image_resized = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image_resized)
  return image_resized

def write_to_tfrecord(writer, target, shape, tfrecord_file):

    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                'target': _bytes_feature(target),
                'shape': _bytes_feature(shape)
                }))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

target = tf.serialize_tensor(return_image_resized(target_file,channels))
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_file)
write_to_tfrecord(writer, target, shape, output_file)
writer.close()
```

However, when I am trying to read the file using below code, I get an error which says "InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 644 values, but the requested shape has 625"

```
def read_from_tfrecord(filenames):
    tfrecord_file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, name='queue')
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, tfrecord_serialized = reader.read(tfrecord_file_queue)


    tfrecord_features = tf.parse_single_example(tfrecord_serialized,
                        features={
                            'target': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                            'shape': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),                
                        }, name='features')


    target = tf.decode_raw(tfrecord_features['target'], tf.uint8)
    shape = tf.decode_raw(tfrecord_features['shape'], tf.int32)

    #Error is coming from the below line of code when I try to reshape it
    target = tf.reshape(target, shape)

    return target, shape

def read_tfrecord(tfrecord_file):
    target, shape = read_from_tfrecord([tfrecord_file])

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        target, shape = sess.run([target, shape])
        print(target.shape)
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

Can someone please help me understand where I am going wrong? How is the tensor getting extra values?

Comment: How do you get `target` in this line `write_to_tfrecord(writer,target,shape, output_file)` ? What is dtype?

Comment: Hi Sharky, I've modified the code to clarify your question. target is a Serialized Tensor. target = tf.serialize_tensor(return_image_resized(target_file,channels)). The tensor before serializing is a unit8 of size (25,25,1) in my current example. I 
 haven't included the sess.run() above explicitly. The tensor is evaluated prior to writing. Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need session or serialize_tensor. Just use `tostring()` on image file

Comment: Thank you Sharky. Will try out your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @Sharky. Your suggestion worked. I also found this post useful to get my understanding right. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427798/tensorflow-tfrecords-tostring-changes-dimension-of-image